# JS quiz -Uncaught Error-

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a quiz with my son to teach him HTML.  But i'm having trouble with some JavaScript(no jquery or any other libraries).  Everything works okay until the end.  It's suppose to tell us how many are right and wrong, but instead we get undefined.

error reads:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'innerHTML' of Question 17 of 16

HTML

```
<body id="body">
    <div id="pokeBallL">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="pokeBallR">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
    <h2 id="tstat"></h2>
    <div id="test">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
(function () {
"use strict";
/*global window,alert*/ 
var UIlogic = {
        myStuff: function () {
            var pos = 0, question, test, tstat, Myquestions, btnCheck, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, correct;
            Myquestions = [
                ["What decade wear you born?","1980's","1990's","2000's","2010's","A"],
                ["What activity do you like more","Gaming","Camping","Travelling","Sleeping","A"],
                ["Pick a color","Black","Pink","Red","Blue","A"],
                ["Pick a number","22","42","4","7","A"],
                ["Choose a weapon","Battleaxe","Sword","Daggers","pen","A"],
                ["Pick an animal","Tiger","Monkey","Elephant","Human","A"],
                ["Pick a music genre","Rock","Hip-hop","Country","Folk","A"],
                ["How many legs do Butterflies have?","4 legs","6 legs","2 legs","3 legs","A"],
                ["How many stripes are on the American flag?","13","15","7","19","A"],
                ["Which is the nearest star?","Centauri A","Sol","Sirius","Proxima Centauri","A"],
                ["Longest river in the world is...?","Mississippi","Nile","Amazon","Ohio","A"],
                ["Pick one...","PS4","PC Master Race","XB One","Puny Apple","A"],
                ["Pop or Soda?","Pop","Both","Soda","Soft Drink","A"],
                ["What is your favorite creature","Amphibian","Mammal","Reptile","Avian","A"],
                ["Pick a squad position","Squad Leader","FTL","","Grenadier","A"],
                ["The Zombie apocalypse has begun! CHoose your path...","Get to lifeboat","Live inside mountains","Hold-up above gas station","Become Zombie","A"]
            ];

            function _(x) {
                return document.getElementById(x);
            }
            function renderQuestion() {
                test = _("test");
                tstat = _("tstat").innerHTML = "Question " +(pos + 1)+ " of " +Myquestions.length;//seems to have an issue here
                if(pos >= Myquestions.length) {
                    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " +correct+ " out of " +Myquestions.length+ " questions correct!</h2>";
                    tstat.innerHTML = "<h2>Test completed</h2>";
                    pos = 0;
                    correct = 0;
                    return false;
                }
                question = Myquestions[pos][0];
                chA = Myquestions[pos][1];
                chB = Myquestions[pos][2];
                chC = Myquestions[pos][3];
                chD = Myquestions[pos][4];
                test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3><hr />";
                test.innerHTML += "<h4><input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA+"</h4><br />";
                test.innerHTML += "<h4><input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>"+chB+"</h4><br />";
                test.innerHTML += "<h4><input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'>"+chC+"</h4><br />";
                test.innerHTML += "<h4><input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'>"+chD+"</h4><br />";
                test.innerHTML += "<button id='btnCheck' class='btnClass'>Submit</button>";


                btnCheck = document.getElementById("btnCheck");
                btnCheck.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer, false);
            }
            renderQuestion();
            function checkAnswer() {
                choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
                for(var i = 0; i<choices.length; i++) {
                    if(choices[i].checked){
                        choice = choices[i].value;
                    }
                }
                if(choice == Myquestions[pos][5]) {//somewhere here doesn't seem right either.
                    correct++;
                }
                pos++;
                renderQuestion();
            }
        }
    };
window.onload = function () {
    UIlogic.myStuff();
};
}());
```

Comment: Question 17 of 16? Isn't there an issue there?

Comment: yes, and i have been trying for about a week now to figure out why...no success yet.

Comment: it's probably something simple that i missed, i just know it.

Comment: Read what it says. Question ***17*** of 16. 17 is bigger than 16. This is probably an issue with the an index being out of bounds or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... i changed

```
var correct;
```

to

```
var correct = 0;
```

turns out, the index wasn't counting because correct was reading NAN

Although, i should make a function to check the radios first before entering, a non-answer will answer correctly. This is what i made for that...

```
function checkAnswer() {
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    var found = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      if (choices[i].checked) {
        choice = choices[i].value;

        found = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(found == 1)
            {
            alert("Please Select Radio");
            return false;
            }
    if (choice === Myquestions[pos][5]) { //somewhere here doesn't seem right either.
      correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

separate this line

```
tstat = _("tstat").innerHTML = "Question " +(pos + 1)+ " of " +Myquestions.length;//seems to have an issue here
```

into this:

```
tstat = _("tstat");
tstat.innerHTML = "Question " +(pos + 1)+ " of " + (Myquestions.length + 1);
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/VLmOmy?editors=001)

Comment: This stopped the error, but now the checkAnswer function is not evaluating correct answers now.

But this solved one issue, thanks.